# Table column spacing in Plain TeX with \settabs

Tags: tables, tex-core, plain-tex

In Plain TeX I need to reduce the space between 2 columns in a 2 column
table. How to do this? I am simply using `\settabs 2 \columns`, but one column is
at the left of the page, but the second is on the right. How do you put the columns
side by side?

Answer (score 3):

The syntax `\settabs n\columns` spreads the *n* columns across the entire width of the page (`\hsize`, actually).  You can use `\settabs\+ <sample line>\cr` to tell TeX how wide the widest line is, then you can add spacing as you wish in the `<sample line>`:

```tex
%                    VVVVVVVVV adjust space
\settabs\+widest line\hskip6pt&widest line again\cr % sample line
\+hello&world\cr
\+sample&table\cr
\+widest line&widest line again\cr
```

But I'd prefer using `\halign` directly:

```tex
\halign{\tabskip=6pt %
  #\hfil&#\hfil\cr
hello&world\cr
sample&table\cr
widest line&widest line again\cr}
```

Both tables produce the same output:

> [image]